# Has anyone tried using feedzilla to display mysql queries?

Tags: mysql, json

Pretty much what it says, has anyone tried using feedzilla to display mysql queries? I want to use the tool but need what's being fed in to be from my mysql tables not from wherever they're pulling it from. Just wondering if anyone had already done that and knew how before I started punching around myself.

http://feedzilla.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Feedzilla](http://www.feedzilla.com/gallery) ***only displays RSS Feeds from web sites, there is no way to use it to display your mysql queries***, you will need to build it by yourself.

If you want to make something similier to it, then it is all about structuring, styling and displaying the json-formatted results fetched from mysql database using php or what ever your application into your web pages.